# How to add a image to a textured wall?

Tags: texturing

So i've been working on a little projekt and i want to place an graffiti on a Wall, but i couldn't find any informations about how i can actually do that. The wall textures consists of a colour, reflection and a normal map, which are connected to a Princibled BSDF, which is connected to the Material Output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic way to do it is this one:

- Create your graffiti with a transparent background (on Photoshop or directly on Blender, in that case create a new image with a 100% transparent alpha background).
- Mix your brick image and your graffiti image with a *Mix Shader*.
- Plug the *Alpha* output of the graffiti *Image Texture* node into the *Factor* input of the *Mix Shader* so that the transparent surface of the graffiti image will work as a mask.
- You can create a second UVMap to manipulate the graffiti coordinates, size or rotation, independently from the brick texture: In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *UVMaps*, add a new one with the +, then unwrap again your object, then, before the *Image Texture* of the graffiti, create an *Input* node > *UV Map*, and choose this second unwrap as the UV coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Instead of mixing two shaders (which will be botch require computing time) just to mix some pixels, you should use only one diffuse shader, and mix the two texture nodes with a color mix

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly but what would i need to do, if i want to scale or rotate the graffiti? Or will i need to do that on the image itself with for example photoshop?

Comment: Add a node Vector→Mapping and plug it into the vector input of a image texture node. You have the scale settings here.

Comment: @Lennuk, you could create a second unwrap for the graffiti only, in that case, before the Image Texture/Graffiti, create an Input node > UV Map, and choose this second unwrap as the coordinate of this UV Map.

Comment: @Lolock, yes, I was hesitating between mix shader and color mix, I didn't know mix required more time

Comment: Alright, that was very good to know, thank you very much, my problem is solved. :-)